# Add dynamic controls using jquery in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to create two dynamic dropdown through a button using jquery in ruby on rails, below is the code of a button in ruby on rails:

```
<tr>
         <td align="center">
            <table id="Controls">
            </table>
            <form method="post" action="" class="button_to">
            <div><input value="btnAdd" type="submit" /></div>
            </form>

         </td>
      </tr>
```

And below is the jquery code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function() {
     $("input[value='btnAdd']").click(function(e)
     {
          e.preventDefault();
          alert("Hassan");

    // var field = $("#field").val();
     var year = new Date().getFullYear();
     var DDL_fromProfession=document.createElement("select");
     DDL_fromProfession.setAttribute("name","ParametersFromProf");
     DDL_fromProfession.setAttribute("id","DDL_FromProYear");
     for (var i = year; i >= 1950; --i) 
     {
       var option=document.createElement("option");
       option.setAttribute("value",i);
       option.text=i;
       DDL_fromProfession.appendChild(option);
     }

     var DDL_ToProfession=document.createElement("select");
     DDL_ToProfession.setAttribute("name","ParametersToProf");
     DDL_ToProfession.setAttribute("id","DDL_ToProYear");
     for (var i = year; i >= 1950; --i) 
     {
      var j = 0;
        if (j != year) 
       {
         var option=document.createElement("option");
         option.setAttribute("value",i);
         option.text=i;
         DDL_ToProfession.appendChild(option);
       }
       else
       {
          var option=document.createElement("option");
         option.setAttribute("value","parent");
         option.text="parent";
         DDL_ToProfession.appendChild(option);
       }
     }

     var table=document.getElementById("Controls");
     var tr = document.createElement("tr");
     var td = document.createElement("td");
     var button=document.createElement("button");
     button.setAttribute("class","btn_rmv");
     button.setAttribute("type","button");
     var br=createElementById("br");
     td.appandChild("From "+DDL_FromProfession + " To "+DDL_ToProfession);
     td.appandChild(br);
     td.appandChild(button);
     tr.appendChild(td);
     table.appandChild(tr);

  });
 });
</script>
```

The above jquery code alerting "Hassan" But its not add dynamic controls, and when i check an error in IE10, it show an error below:

```
Message: 'createElementById' is undefined
Line: 98
Char: 6
Code: 0
```

And line 98 is `var br=createElementById("br");` in jquery code, so I don't understand where I make mistake at line `var br=createElementById("br");`. Kindly suggest me waiting for reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var br= $("<br />");
```

instead of:

```
var br=createElementById("br");
```